# Python keep scrollbar at end point

Tags: python, listbox, scrollbar, tkinter

So when assigning Scrollbars to Listboxes, if you later on insert new lines, the scroll thumb does not "update". I want the scroll thumb to be set to the bottom of my vertical scrollbar everytime i insert new lines into my listbox.

I've tried:

```
mylistbox.yview = command("moveto", 1)
mylistbox.yview = ('moveto', 1)
mylistbox.yview = ('moveto', '1.0')
myscrollbar.set = ('0.0', '1.0')
```

And none of them works.

How do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see 'see'

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/32d00fb2ad61cab3

Comment: True, but Thanks 'noob oddy', one easy line of code solved it.